# Яке походження слова "нестелепна"?

Tags: етимологія

Яке походження слова "нестелепний"?

Answer (score 1):

Прикметник *нестеле́пний* я наразі не бачу в жодному словнику. Але де-факто він уживається (зокрема згадується в [Д. X. Баранник, «Народнорозмовний складник лексичної та фразеологічної систем національної мови (на захист розмовного стилю)»](https://movoznavstvo.org.ua/index.php?option=com_attachments&task=download&id=440)).

Припускаю, що він походить від іменника *нестеле́па*, який уже фіксується частіше, зокрема [в Грінченка](http://hrinchenko.com/slovar/znachenie-slova/32843-nestelepa.html), [в інших](https://r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%B0&scope=all&dicts=all&highlight=on) і в [«Словниках України online» від УМІФ](http://lcorp.ulif.org.ua/dictua/).

Походження цього іменника «Етимологічний словник української мови» в 7 томах пояснює [так](https://goroh.pp.ua/%D0%95%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%96%D1%8F/%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BF):

> очевидно, результат контамінації форм розтеле́па і недоте́па «тс.»